# NodeJS function returns before intended

Tags: node.js

I have a function that loops and makes some API calls:

```
sendText(clientArr){
    clientArr.forEach(function (textObject, index) {
        var myRequest = {
            body: textObject.messageContent,
            to: { phoneNumber: textObject.phoneNumber },
            rules: ['sms']
        };

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: comapiUrl,
            headers:
                {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                    authorization: 'Bearer ' + yourComapiAccessToken
                },
            body: myRequest,
            json: true
        };
        console.log('');
        console.log('Calling Comapi...');
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);

            console.log("HTTP status code returned: " + response.statusCode);

            // Check status
            if (response.statusCode == 201)
            {
                // All ok
                console.log('SMS message successfully sent via Comapi "One" API');
            }
            else
            {
                // Something went wrong
                console.log('Something went wrong!');
            }

            console.log(body);
            return response

        });
    })
};
```

This function got called from here:

```
function callAPI(req, res, apiMethod) {
let params = {};
params = req.params;
params.headers = req.headers;
if (req.method.toLowerCase() != 'get') {
    params.post = req.body;
}

params.query = req.query;
params.middlewareStorage = req.middlewareStorage;

apiMethod(params)
    .success(function (result) {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .failure(function (error) {
        console.logger.error(error);
        if (!(Object.prototype.toString.call(error) === '[object Object]')) {
            error = {success: false, error: error};
        }
        console.logger.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
}
```

router:

```
router.post('/sendText', function (req,res) {
    callAPI(req, res, fn.bind(apiObj, 'sendText'));
});
```

What I am getting in response is:

POST /clients/sendText 500 320.615 ms - 1514
2018-01-04 02:03:38.887 DEBUG app - HTTP status code returned: 201

It returns with 500 error:
Cannot read property 'success' of undefined\n    at callAPI (

before I intended it to return.

How do I fix this?

Comment: There seems to be some connecting code missing in the question. What is `apiMethod`. Is it `sendText`?.

Comment: updated...........

Comment: What is `fn` in the router?

Comment: A custom library that has bind method as follows:function bind(obj, fnFieldName) {
    return obj[fnFieldName].bind(obj);
}

Answer (score 0):

The sendText method is returning nothing and thus `undefined`. And hence that does not have `success` or `failure` method. However, even if it returns a valid response. The response should have success and failure method.

A better way here will to use promises. You can return promise from api method and change the callAPI method to use the promise interface.

> sendText method (using `request-promise` instead of `request`)

```
sendText(clientArr) {
    return Promise.all(clientArr.map(function (textObject, index) {
        var myRequest = {
            body: textObject.messageContent,
            to: { phoneNumber: textObject.phoneNumber },
            rules: ['sms']
        };

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: comapiUrl,
            headers:
                {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'content-type': 'application/json',
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                    authorization: 'Bearer ' + yourComapiAccessToken
                },
            body: myRequest,
            json: true,
            resolveWithFullResponse: true
        };
        console.log('');
        console.log('Calling Comapi...');
        return request(options)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);

            console.log("HTTP status code returned: " + response.statusCode);

            // Check status
            if (response.statusCode == 201)
            {
                // All ok
                console.log('SMS message successfully sent via Comapi "One" API');
            }
            else
            {
                // Something went wrong
                console.log('Something went wrong!');
            }

            console.log(body);
            return response
        });
    })
};
```

> callApi

```
function callAPI(req, res, apiMethod) {
    let params = {};
    params = req.params;
    params.headers = req.headers;
    if (req.method.toLowerCase() != 'get') {
        params.post = req.body;
    }

    params.query = req.query;
    params.middlewareStorage = req.middlewareStorage;

    apiMethod(params)
    .then(function (result) {
        res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.logger.error(error);
        if (!(Object.prototype.toString.call(error) === '[object Object]')) {
            error = {success: false, error: error};
        }
        console.logger.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    });
}
```